# PHP/MySQL Search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have hit a stumbling block and hoping fellow stackoverflow people will help me out. I am trying to setup a category search. I have a numeric value for a category I assign to the product, and all works perfect, however when I am loading a category i only see what is actually assigned that id, not the subcats which is what I am needing it to do.

```
Category db layout
-category_id
-category_name
-parent_id
-categoryslug
-subcategory

Example for database would be  
-category_id = 1
-category_name = test
-parent_id = NULL
-categoryslug = test
-subcategory = 2,3,4
```

I need the results of 2,3,4 to show up as well as category 1. Below is my SQL statement that I'm needing help with

```
function searchCategory($q, $start, $end, $categoryid) {
    include $_SESSION['db'];
    $q = $str = (!empty($_GET['q']) ? preg_replace('/[,\s+]/', '%', $_GET['q']) : '');
    if($categoryid == '') {$categoryid = '%'; }
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT id, maincategory, title, description, qty, price, featphoto FROM products
            WHERE CONCAT(
                REPLACE(title, ' ',''),
                REPLACE(description, ' ','')
                )
            LIKE :category
            AND (maincategory = :maincategory)
            LIMIT ".$start.", 12";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':category', '%'.$q.'%');
        $s->bindValue(':maincategory',  $categoryid);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error.' . $e->getMessage();
        moduleError($error);
        exit();
    }
    include('tpl/search.tpl.php');
}
```

Comment: It would help if you created a sqlfiddle for us to see. Also an example of what output you are expecting all together based on which conditions.

Answer (score 0):

From Your question it seem as if you want to get results that match your category and results that match its subcategories as well.

You may be able to use the `in` clause here is a link to an [in clause tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Your query might look something like this

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, maincategory, title, description, qty, price, featphoto FROM products
        WHERE CONCAT(
            REPLACE(title, ' ',''),
            REPLACE(description, ' ','')
            )
        LIKE :category
        AND (maincategory = :maincategory OR category IN (SELECT subcategory FROM products WHERE maincategory =:maincategory))
        LIMIT ".$start.", 12";
```

What the added bit does is it does a sub query getting all the subcategories for a category and then if any of them match category that row would be a possible row.

In your example case it would get [2,3,4] for the sub query.
And then any category that didn't (or did) have the same maincategory but had 2,3 or 4 for a category would show up in your possible results, which you limit to 12 results from your offset.